# How to bulk sell 5000 NFTs to OpenSea's Polygon network programmatically?

Tags: nft, polygon, opensea

I have 5000 NFTs generated by https://nft-generator.art. How can I bulk sell 5000 NFTs to OpenSea's Polygon network programmatically? Doing so via selenium & chromium driver is unreliable. Any alternative?

I know opensea-js can sell NFTs to ETH network, but seems the support of Polygon network is not ready yet.

p.s. I'm using MetaMask wallet.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue, any solutions?